# Does Ubuntu Update the Official Download Version to Reflect Changes

Tags: 13.04, updates

Does Ubuntu update the [official download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) to reflect changes since a version was released?  I already have a copy of 13.04, as released in April 2013, on a DVD.  I am contemplating installing 13.04 on another computer.

If Ubuntu does update the copy available for download, I will undertake a new download.  Otherwise, I will install the April 2013 version and then run the update program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for the 6 monthly releases, for example 13.04 won't get updated, but soon we should get 13.10.
The LTS versions do get updates.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 0):

Once the support cycles is over you will have to-reinstall with a new disc that not going to happen until next year. Your current copy form april is good to go. Once you have installed it you will have to install updates though to get fully up-to-date